# Highmaps svg path issue - Data not flowing into certain counties on US map

Tags: svg, highcharts

I've built an app using Highmaps.js, but I keep getting the following error message:

"Error: Invalid value for ..." then it gives a bunch of path coordinates that I'm not sure how to fix.

The result of this error is that none of the data for the states of Florida, Delaware or Connecticut show up. I'm guessing that it hasn't even been pushed into the map since noting happens when you hover over those states.

Do I need to make a new svg? Can I edit the path of the old one or fix the current one somehow?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Here's the prototype of the site:

www.graysonmendenhall.com/PAN2014

Answer (score 1):

You have some name mismatches between your map SVG Paths and your data.  For instance, in your map you'll have:

```
{
    "name": "Levy County, FL",
    "path": "M2393,1490L2409,1493L2412,1511L2404,1513L2406,1524L2406,1524L2405,1525L2401,1527L2397,1527L2396,1527L2395,1527L2394,1528L2393,1529L2393,1530L2393,1527L2392,1526L2389,1520L2387,1519L2365,1513L2370,1509L2373,1504L2374,1499L2376,1490L2393,1490"
},
```

But in the data it's:

```
{
    name: "Levy, FL" // No County!!
    value: 3218
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I'll comb through the data and fix those names

Comment: Ok, so I went through the data and made sure the Florida, Delaware and Connecticut names match. But now, only the 1987 data shows up in those states while the other five datasets still have those states' data missing. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Did you change the names in the SVG paths or data?  If in the data did you update each year's json?  Are you sure your browser isn't caching an older file?

Comment: I left the names in the svg paths alone and just changed each year's json file. And my browser was, in fact, caching all the other json files except the one it initially loads when the site loads. It works great now! Thank you so much for your help!!!